# Cant get usb stick to work in windows 7 qemu VM

Tags: qemu

I'm having trouble to get my usb stick to work in qemu VM windows 7, I'm using Windows 10. I tried the following command:

qemu-system-x86_64 -boot d -m 4G -drive file=win7.img -drive if=none,id=usbstick,file=usb.img -usb -cdrom win7.iso -device usb-ehci,id=ehci -device usb-storage,bus=ehci.0,drive=usbstick

I used ehci, because my win7 vm doesnt support usb 3, so when i run this command i get to see the usb.img contents in my explorer on windows 7 VM.

I also tried with host command like this:

qemu-system-x86_64 -boot d -m 4G -drive file=win7.img -usb -cdrom win7.iso -device usb-ehci,id=ehci -device usb-host,bus=ehci.0,hostbus=0,hostaddr=2

Anyway a command like this gives me somehow some results, nemely that my usb stick disappears from my Win 10, so that means something gets emulated on my windows 7 VM right, I got my USB stick connected to a hub, and so when I check my Windows 7 VM, it finds 2 usb ubs somehow instead of one, so it sees the usb stick as a hub?
So I thought, lets plug my USB stick directly without hub, but then when i check my settings, it says address of the USB stick (not 2 anymore) 0000000D, when I try address 0 at the command it doesn't work, when I try address 0D, it says address must be integer.

After all that, I als tried with vendorid and product id, connecting like a way I saw on a youtue video, but that also didn't gave any results. Could someone please help me out with one of the ways, -device usb-storage to work, or -device usb-host to work. Thanks alot, great community. Have agreat day. Greetings

I tried -device usb-host and i tried -device usb-storage.